# Objective C Input is a number

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Hey I'm learning Objective C and I have one question. I Have one Text Field the Input should be a Number with this number i want to calculate something but how do I do that ?

```
NSNumber *test;

if ([prospekt_1 intValue] == 0) {
    test = [prospekt_1 intValue] * 2.50;
    [ergebnis_prospekt_1 setIntValue:test];
}
```

Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: What is prospekt_1?, please post more code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NSNumber `test` is an object pointer.  You're assigning an int to an object, essentially making it a pointer to an invalid memory address.

You want `test = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[prospekt_1 intValue] * 2.50];`

This creates a new object (NSNumber) and assigns it to the pointer `test`.

### or

You could skip the NSNumber object entirely and just assign the int value directly.  Why waste memory on an object? An int is smaller memory footprint.

Replace `NSNumber *` with `int` and it will also work and be more memory efficient.

Comment: yeah this worked thanks :) but the result of this should be sent to `ergebnis_prospekt_1` how do I do that ?

Comment: What is ergebnis_prospekt_1?  Is it another text field?  If so, use `setValue:` (In this case, you will need the object version, not just a straight `int`.  Also, make sure it's properly connected through an outlet via IB.

Comment: `ergebnis_prospekt_1` is another textfield they are connected in IB and i used `setValue:test` but it doesn't worked

Comment: Do NSLog on ergebnis_prospekt_1 and make sure it's not nil that means it wasn't connected properly in IB.